# Silverlight How to create a usercontrol whose properties are customizable

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm sure this is a real beginner question; I'm just having trouble figuring out how to search for it.

I have a simple UserControl (MyNewControl) that only has three controls, one of which is the following label:

```
<sdk:Label x:Name="Title" />
```

In another control, then, I want to use MyNewControl, like this:

```
<local:MyNewControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyNewGuy" />
```

What do I need to do so that this second control can, for example, set a gradient background for my Title label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define the desired dependency property in your UserControl:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public Brush LabelBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(LabelBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To assign the value of your property to the child label, you can bind using the ElementName property of the binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="400"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="UserControl"
         >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:Label x:Name="Title"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Title" Background="{Binding LabelBackground, ElementName=UserControl}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you are using Silverlight 5, you can also set a [RelativeSource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202484/Silverlight-5-Features-Ancestor-Relative-Source-Bi) to your binding, instead of internally naming your UserControl:

```
<sdk:Label Background="{Binding LabelBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Then, when using your UserControl, you just set (or bind) the LabelBackground to the desired value:

```
<local:MyUserControl LabelBackground="Red"/>
```

Just to note, you can also create a [CustomControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/176829/How-to-create-a-Custom-Control-in-Silverlight) instead of a UserControl, add the dependency property to it the same way and [use a TemplateBinding when defining its template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177974/How-to-implement-Template-Binding-in-Silverlight-C).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your custom control . Say you defined LableBG as an dependency property in your custom control and do the binding with an Background  of your defined Label control in xaml . And when you use your custom control in another control you can set the LableBG of it from xaml or else from code behind.

Note : the type of your defined dependency property should be of Brush

For eg :

Defining Dependency Property in cs file of your custom control :

```
/1. Declare the dependency property as static, readonly field in your class.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LableBGProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LableBG",                      //Property name
        typeof(Brush),                  //Property type
        typeof(MySilverlightControl),   //Type of the dependency property provider
        null );//Callback invoked on property value has changes

<sdk:Label x:Name="Title" Background="{Binding LableBG }" /> (Custom Control)


<local:MyNewControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyNewGuy" LableBG="Red" /> (Another control)
```

Comment: That won't work as {Binding LableBG } is binding to the Label's DataContext, not to its parent UserControl.